# Default values coming up as undefined from Observable object

Tags: javascript, nativescript

The below example snippet has a structure some what similar to a view model and controller that I have. Any idea why the default values in the Observable object wouldn't instantiate when I instantiate the view model?
If in another method in the controller I try to access I get undefined.

```
/**
 * some-view-model.js
 */

var Observable = require('data/observable').Observable;

function SomeViewModel(){
    var model = new Observable({
        name: "",
        someBool: true
    });

  return model;
}

module.exports = SomeViewModel;


/**
 * some-view.js
 */
var SomeViewModel = require('some-view-model');

var SomeView = function(){};
var ViewModel = new SomeViewModel();

SomeView.prototype.viewLoaded = function(args){
    // do some stuff
};

SomeView.prototype.foo = function(){
  // below returns undefined rather than true, why??
  ViewModel.get('someBool')
};

module.exports = new SomeView()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the part that is loading the Some-view file is doing:

```
var someview = require('some-view.js');
someview.foo();
```

Then this should be working fine in NativeScript; I just tested this in v1.7.1 and 2.01 of the runtimes and my ViewModel.get('someBool') returns true.